# Wpf storyboard play animation

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard

I'm new in wpf storyboard. I want you to ask if how can i play an animation after playing current animation with the use of conditional statement? Because i have buttons than needed to play (show them from screen) after the current animation is stop playing.

Comment: In Software, everything is possible it is just a matter on how you tackle the issue. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Were our answers any help? Let us know and accept if so

Answer (score 3):

While creating the animation you want to create a callback to Completed event.

```
...
System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard storyBoard = (System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)FindResource("storyboardName");
storyBoard.Completed += new EventHandler(storyBoard_Completed);

BeginStoryboard(storyBoard);
...

void storyBoard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard storyBoard = (System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)FindResource("nextAnim");
    BeginStoryboard(storyBoard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JeremyK's answer, you may be able to do everything in a single storyboard by setting the start time of the next animation to the end time of the first animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to call you animation, When and Where depends on your project

```
private void PlayStoryboard(string sb)
    {
        Storyboard StoryB = new Storyboard();
        StoryB = (Storyboard)this.FindResource(sb);
        StoryB.Begin();
    }
```